# HTML/Jquery/Javascript Authentication and Authorization Patterns (ASP.NET)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, security, design-patterns

I have a jquery mobile website which has only HTML and Jquery code and back-end data is accessed using Sharepoint webservices. So far so good.

Now , we need to implement Login Authentication for our mobile site and limit access to some pages on our site. There exists another asp.net site(different domain) which has already implemented login functionality in asp.net. We are planning to re-use the same back-end logic of the other site.

Are there any patterns for cross-domain Login? How the Session Management can be done?

Hope I am clear.Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I use CORS for this? If so, how the state management is done?

Comment: Do you plan to share any back end info with the other site? What do these two sites have in common other than the fact that you plan to reuse the same logic?

Comment: It is only for Authentication. We need to validate against the same membership database in the other site. I was looking for a quick solution where we can implement the same functionality with minimal changes.

Answer (score 0):

Cross origin resource sharing seems the way to go! Once the authentication is done by the external asp.net site, every thing else is the very same as non-CORS method.

Check [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) for the browser support for CORS.

And [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2327-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-CORS-AJAX-Requests-Between-jQuery-And-Node-js.htm) is a good blog which demonstrates the usage of CORS.

Hope this help you.

Comment: CORS is fine. How to do session management, instead of authenticating the user using CORS for every request?

Comment: How are you doing it in your current application? Are you not storing a kind of session object?

Comment: As in my question , I have a jquery mobile website which has only HTML and Jquery code and no server side code for session management on the first site . 
If I make a call using CORS to the second site, it gets authenticated and thats fine . But, Do I need to authenticate for subsequent requests to the first site?

Comment: Well, then it would be a series of CORS calls to manage that session. As far as I know. Or, you might want to put in the session management logic in your second site and use CORS only to verify the login and get a valud session.

Comment: This [link](http://avalanche123.com/blog/2011/10/10/cross-domain-javascript-lessons-learned/) might also help you take the call on how many CORS requests you want to use.